# Django (1.4) how to use with template tag to assign several variables

Tags: django, templates, templatetag

I am trying to assign several variables in the same with :

```
{% with 'Foo' as description 'Blah' as description_2 %}
...
{% endwith %}
```

Is there any way to achieve this ? (It works with two `with`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning multiple variables is possible with the new syntax:

```
{% with description='Foo' description_2='Blah' %}
...
{% endwith %}
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#with.